# Invoke-WebRequest Failure

Tags: powershell

The issue is that I got a script from a vendor to pull data from a DB.
The script is having a problem with the Invoke-WebRequest Section.

Here is the Script:

```
$url = @'
https://demo.liquidwarelabs.com/lwl/api?json={"inspector":"0","basis":"users","date":"yesterday","limit":"0","columns":"user_name,login_count","output":"1:html","header":"1"}
'@
$output = "c:\export\Tier1\view1.csv"
Invoke-WebRequest $url -OutFile $output
```

Here is the Error I get:

> Invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was closed: An
>   unexpected error occurred on a send. At C:\Scripts\3.ps1:38 char:1
>   + Invoke-WebRequest $url -OutFile $output
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest],
>   WebException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

Comment: Works for me.  I get a response, though that response is a webpage with the text "Not Authorized" and "HTTP 403".  Are you certain you don't have a proxy (or something else in your internet stack) interfering with the connection?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to URL encode the JSON:

```
$url = 'https://demo.liquidwarelabs.com/lwl/api?json='
$json = '{"inspector":"0","basis":"users","date":"yesterday","limit":"0","columns":"user_name,login_count","output":"1:html","header":"1"}'
$encodedjson = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($json)
$output = "c:\export\Tier1\view1.csv"
Invoke-WebRequest ($url+$encodedjson) -OutFile $output
```

Comment: Thank you - I'll give it a try.

Comment: I had to do `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web` beforehand to get this to work.